# Run *.sh script on double click

Tags: manjaro

I'm on Manjaro and have a shell script which configures the environment for a Java application in the same folder.

I am able to run said shell script in terminal and my Java app starts, everything is fine.

The point is I want to launch my Java app by double click its shell script.
The problem is, I can't assign the terminal as default app to open my script, can't believe it!

And yes, my script begins with 
`#!/bin/sh`

If I go into (file properties> open with) , I can find a lot of unrelated applications,
Execute software/shell extension

.. are the closest hints. There's no terminal to choose. 
There's no button to add another app as launcher for my script.

Comment: Show us how your run the script from the command line.

Comment: You do know that after your shell script exits, the environment it created exits with it?

Comment: **@ctrl-alt-delor**   I execute the shell script writing its full path in quotes and confirm with  return button. Works perfectly.

Comment: **@wurtel 2**    sounds great but manjaro opens the  application bundle of my Java application on double click